# php simplexml check if have child child nod?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have many `xml` file's, I do not want to get the value, but check if they have a child child nod or no. so I use `count` instead of `foreach`. but my code always echo `no` if there have no `$xml->book->date` in the first `$xml->book` roop.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('some.xml');
if (@count($xml->book->date)>0){
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

the xml tree like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Catalog>
    <book>
     <title/><description/><price/>
  </book>
  <book>
     <title/><description/><price/>
     <date/>  //(optional, there may be 0 to n [book] elements having a [date] element in the document)
  </book>
  <book>
     <title/><description/><price/>
  </book>
  <book>
     <title/><description/><price/>
     <date/>
  </book>
</Catalog>
```

For this document the result of the working version of "count($xml->book->date)" should be 2, i.e. > 0

**EDIT**: maybe do not use `count`, but how to check if have or not have `date` childnod in the whole xml file?  Thanks.

Comment: It works as it is supposed to. If there is no `date` element in the first `book`, `count($xml->book->date)` will return 0 and if there is one `date` element in the first `book`, `count($xml->book->date)` will return 1. So what's the issue?

Comment: @Vikk, I do not want to check the first `book`, but I want check all the `book` loop, if there has child nod `data`. so may be do not use `count`, and is there any other way to check if there have `data` in all the xml file? Thanks.

Comment: fish man, I took the liberty of changing the example document. Revert the change if you disapprove.

Comment: @VolkerK, yes, the situation like you edited. and I got the right anwser. thank ou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check in the entire xml document, then I think you'll have to loop through all the book elements-

```
$found = false;
foreach($xml->book as $book)
{
    if(count($book->date)>0)
    {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try with xpath?

```
$date=$xml->xpath('/book/date[1]');

if($date){
    echo 'Yes';
}
else{
   echo 'No';
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need that '@' before count(....). Try without that

Comment: But, since you have several "book"-elements you have to specify which of them you want to check "date" on.

    $xml->book[0]->date